# Why do Google results have a globe icon?

Tags: google-search, google-account

I am using Windows 11 and recently started to see a globe icon on Google results.

If I log out of my Google Account there are no globe icons,

But when I login again, the globe icons show up again..

I tried to remove all extensions and reinstall Google Chrome and it does not help

UPD: I mean all items from Google search result are like that. And none of the items have favicon.

**upd2:** this is fixed now on google side.

[image]

Comment: Regarding Upd2: It's not that the Globe icon was a defect that should fixed, it was a feature that you might not liked / understood. The [answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/169174/88163) looks that provide a good explanation. Is there a reason for not accepting this answer? Please bear in mind that follow up questions should be posted as new questions. If the update is regarding the most recent answer you might leave a commet under that answer or just ignore it (once you reach +125 rep you might dowvote it, and with the higher rep leves even vote to delete it).

Comment: @Rubén, the issue was different - Google showed every search result with the globe icon. None of favicons were shown. Google did fix this at the moment, and now results do show favicons where available

Comment: It looks that you have to spend more time learning about Google. This is pinned in the Google Search Community [\[FAQ\] My Google Search looks different: Google Live Experiments](https://support.google.com/websearch/thread/110115253/faq-my-google-search-looks-different-google-live-experiments?hl=en)

Answer (score 6):

This shouldn't be a reason for you to freak out, and yes... it's perfectly normal. Want an Explanation? Here you go:

Google search results with globe symbols imply that the result is a publicly available webpage rather than a customised search result. However, if you are connected into your Google account in Chrome and see a little personal profile image or a circular symbol with the initial letter of your name, this shows that the result is a personalised search result, tailored to you based on prior searches and other variables.

To tailor your search results and present you with the most pertinent content, Google makes use of a variety of signals, including your location, search history, and information from your Google account. Your Google Photos, information from your Google Calendar, and regularly visited websites may all be found in the tailored search results. The outcome is thus not individualised and is the same for all users if you see a globe icon.

You stop giving Google access to information from your account that may be used to customise your search results when you log out of your Google account. As a result, only publicly available webpages will be displayed in your search results, and you won't get any more customised search results. When you log out of your Google account, the globe symbols that serve as a visual depiction of this shift disappear, signalling that you are now viewing a non-personalized version of the search results.

The globe symbols essentially serve as a reminder that your Google account may have an impact on your search results and that logging out would eliminate that impact and provide you with a more neutral, non-tailored view of the search results.

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to disable showing an icon? My wife's Google Chrome does not show the globe, would like the same..

Comment: Sadly, there is no official way to stop Google search results from displaying globe symbols. These symbols are a feature of the Google Search user interface and are there to tell you of the type of search results you are viewing. However, if you'd rather not see these indicators, you may try using an incognito window or the private browsing option in your web browser, as these settings don't save or utilise data from your Google account to tailor your search results. By doing this, the globe icons won't appear and your search results will only include publicly available URLs.

Comment: Could you please tell, is it expected that search results items do not have favicons? Like all results are only have the globe icon

Comment: Yes, It is normal for some search results items not to have a favicon, which can be due to many reasons, one being the site doesn't simply have a favicon at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the globe favicons by using the uBlock extension with the filter "google.com##.H9lube"

Comment: Your answer was automatically flagged by the system because of its length.  I think it could be improved by including more information as to how the OP would go about doing what you are suggesting. Keep contributing.

Comment: From [answer] ·Brevity is acceptable but fuller explanations are better·.